# pROC Package in R - Run without Call and Data Information in RMarkdown

Tags: r, roc, proc-r-package

Anytime you create a ROC Curve with using pROC::roc() additional Information like the code itself and AUC will be plotted in rmarkdown by default below the plot.

Does anyone know how to print the ROC-Curve without the Call and Data information?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDgWM.jpg)

**Code**

```
roc(label, score.4ISS,
plot = TRUE,
legacy.axes = TRUE)
```

Thank you :)

Comment: How are you running the code? This doesn't look like vanilla R.

Comment: You can run this code: `library(pROC)

label = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)

score.4ISS = c(1,2,3,1,2,6,7,7,7,5,4)

roc(label, score.4ISS,
    plot = TRUE,
    legacy.axes = TRUE)` The Problem is about the additional Information (see Example) of the plot.

Comment: This is the printed output, it normally isn't part of the plot. Are you on Windows? This doesn't look like the R console nor Rstudio...

Comment: Yes its a Markdown output. In RStudio - when you run it in a script - the Call and Data information is printed in the console and the plot seperately.

Comment: Can you please edit your question to make it clear for other people who read the QA that this is about markdown? For instance you could include the whole markdown block (including the `\`\`\`r` part)?

Answer (score 0):

This is because objects are implicitly `print`ed in R when they are not assigned to variables. This means that:

```
roc(label, score.4ISS, ...)
```

is equivalent to

```
print(roc(label, score.4ISS, ...))
```

which prints call and data information. If you assign the ROC curve to an object, it won't be printed, and you can decide what to print yourself, for instance only the AUC (or nothing at all).

```
my_roc <- roc(label, score.4ISS, plot = TRUE, legacy.axes = TRUE)
print(auc(my_roc))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to my problem is to assign `roc()` to an object. Then it prints ROC without the additional information and without using a additional `print()` command.

**With Information**

```
roc(label, score.4ISS)
```

**Without Information**

```
my_roc <- roc(label, score.4ISS)
```